# on flushing magento cache storage error message is displayed

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I flush cache storage from backend some error is displayed.

Showing 
"There has been an error processing your request"

Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\sql\catalog_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.0.9-1.6.0.0.10.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity_group_price' already exists

and after that I have to install magento from starting.

Is there any way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If that script only adds a table `catalog_product_entity_group_price` then you can easily skip it. Open your database, select your Magento DB and search the `core_resource` table for `catalog_setup` key. You will have there columns `version` and `data_version`, I believe.

Just update these 2 columns with value 1.6.0.0.10 and clear cache again.

If that script contains more than just creating the table, then you can comment out for the moment the part responsible for table creation.

Comment: Another error show after editing catalog_setup table Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\SalesRule\sql\salesrule_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.2-1.6.0.3.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'salesrule_website' already exists

Comment: Similar thing do here. This time for salesrule_setup

Answer (score 0):

There has been an error processing your request

```
#0 C:\wamp\www\magento-1.7.0.2\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento-1.7.0.2\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.3')
#2 C:\wamp\www\magento-1.7.0.2\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.3')
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento-1.7.0.2\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento-1.7.0.2\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\wamp\www\magento-1.7.0.2\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\wamp\www\magento-1.7.0.2\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\magento-1.7.0.2\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

follow step:-
goto phpMyAdmin then select ur database in this already 219 table is available choose coupon_aggregrated table in this change period column value 0000-00-00 solu ur problem easily.
bye chilku ngcca

Comment: Please check your code formatting before you post your answer. Try to write in clear, precise (as far as possible) sentences.